# Limits single fluorophore, simultaneous absorption and emission

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, photon-emission, fluorescence

So I've been trying to find out what the limitations are for single fluorophores. What I know is that a fluorophore is excited by a photon in too a higher excited state, it then relaxes and later emits a photon (accordign to it's bandgap I assume).
Every state is a discrete (quantum) state and therefor only specific energy levels can be obtained and small enough wavelength is required.

What I'm not sure about and is whether a **single fluorophore** can absorp multiple high energy photons simultaneously. As far as I *know/understood* an excited state consist of one or more electrons occupying higher energy levels.
Now if it's only a single electron then I would think that it would be possible for a fluorophore to absorb multiple photons and have multiple electrons in the excited state. Thus emitting multiple photons in a shorter timespan than it's relaxation time.
If it's not the case then things would get much more complicated of course.

My final question is thus as follows, can a **single fluorophore** (molecule) absorb more than one photon before relaxing? Regarding of the answer I would greatly appreciate a fundamental explanation as to what exactly happens and why it can or can not.

If it can not absorb more than one photon before relaxing then that would mean that there's a maximum intensity you could use to gain greater emission. I'm though curious what would happen, if it can not absorb more photons than one, once you keep bombarding it with more photons during that time.